# Environment variables in NodeJs using cPanel

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, cpanel, next.js, production-environment

So I'm using cPanel with Setup Node.js App plugin for a Next.js app. (don't asky why cPanel)

Everything is working as expected in development, except for environment variables in production, I set up them manually from the cPanel interface, I restarted/stopped the app, logging the process.env on the server and I don't see the env variables there (not to say when trying to call them they are undefined).

When doing
`res.json(JSON.stringify(process.env));` i get a bunch of variables except for the one I manually wrote in cPanel variables interface.

It is important for me to store these variables as secret key because they are API credentials.

Anyone know what I might have misconfigured or had this problem?

Comment: How you are setting this env variable?

Comment: I added them from interface that exists inside "Setup Node.js App" plugin from cPanel, after i select edit/create an app, there I find a column called "Environment variables" at the end of the page. Added them there and expected to work.

Comment: I'm using Node.js express app via cPanel. But it could not read the envrionments that defined in cPanel. I don't want to persit secret keys in the `.env` files. Looks like it has a bug on cPanel Node.js module.

Comment: I used environment variable using `dotenv` but it seems the value of variable starting with `**$**` will be a problem.

Comment: Hi, is there anything with express.js application i am getting the same error but i never used next.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never mind, found the answer, apparenlty was a Next.js misconfiguration. I had to add the following lines of code inside `next.config.js` in order to read env variables on build version.

```
require('dotenv').config();

module.exports = {
  env: {
    EMAIL_NAME: process.env.EMAIL_NAME,
    EMAIL_PASSWORD: process.env.EMAIL_PASSWORD,
    GETRESPONSE_API_KEY: process.env.GETRESPONSE_API_KEY
  }
};
```

Where EMAIL_NAME, EMAIL_PASSWORD, GETRESPONSE_API_KEY were the variables defined by me on cPanel interface

Comment: Hi, is there anything with express.js application i am getting the same error but i never used next.js

Comment: I don't believe this answer to be true. Did you build it while .env file was on the root folder? If so, it's not reading the environment variables in your cpanel, it's just accessing the env file while building and replacing the variables with the values

Comment: I don't own a cPanel website anymore, not sure if things changed in past 2y and 6months, but most likely they did.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure the .env file is added manually in your root folder is its often ignored in git while pushing your code.